# How to keep STOMP connection longer?

Tags: java, websocket, stomp

I'm currently writing a test echo client for STOMP over Websocket server in Java. However I noticed that the connection is somehow unpredictable as usually it's closed before message received thus client produces exception

```
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Unable to write the complete message as the WebSocket connection has been closed
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:282) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.sendCloseMessage(WsSession.java:584) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
```

And here is my simple test client

```
@Slf4j
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class, classes = Application.class)
@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort = true)
public class WebSocketConfigurationIT {

@Value("${local.server.port}")
private int port;

private SockJsClient sockJsClient;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    final WebSocketTransport webSocketTransport = new WebSocketTransport(new StandardWebSocketClient());
    final RestTemplateXhrTransport restTemplateXhrTransport = new RestTemplateXhrTransport(new RestTemplate());
    sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(Lists.newArrayList(webSocketTransport, restTemplateXhrTransport));
}

@Test
public void testEcho() throws Exception {
    CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    StompSessionHandler stompSessionHandler = new StompSessionHandlerAdapter() {};
    WebSocketStompClient webSocketStompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);
    webSocketStompClient.setDefaultHeartbeat(new long[]{0, 0});
    webSocketStompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
    ListenableFuture<StompSession> connect = webSocketStompClient.connect("ws://localhost:{port}/api/ws/media/socket", stompSessionHandler, port);
    StompSession session = connect.get();
    String message = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    log.debug("sending {}", message);
    session.send("/echo/" + message, null);

    session.subscribe("/topic/echo/" + message, new StompFrameHandler() {
        @Override
        public Type getPayloadType(final StompHeaders headers) {
            return String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleFrame(final StompHeaders headers, final Object payload) {
            log.debug("received {}", payload);
            assertEquals(message, payload);
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        }
    });
    // wait for messange being echoed
    if (!countDownLatch.await(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
        fail("message not received");
    }
}

@Controller
public static class EchoController {

    @MessageMapping("/echo/{message}")
    public String echo(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor simpMessageHeaderAccessor, @DestinationVariable("message") String message) {
        log.debug("header {}", simpMessageHeaderAccessor);
        log.debug("echoed {}", message);
        return message;
    }
}
}
```

And configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/api/ws/media/socket").withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    super.configureMessageBroker(registry);
    //registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/");
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
}
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using {0,0} as your heartbeat configuration? Try configuring a heartbeat, it might help keep your connection alive.

Comment: @kazagistar, thank you for your response. I removed heartbeat configuration and it is able to receive more echo messages. But the long stack trace does not go away