# Struggling with Spring WebSocket + ActiveMQ (Relay Broker) + Connection gets closed even with heartbeat

Tags: activemq-classic, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I've been struggling to increase the inactivity timeout on Activemq (changing settings in activemq.xml don't seem to work). I see the heartbeats being exchanged in the browser console (SockJS client) but after a while I get Connection closed by broker. Below are my configurations:

activemq.xml:

```xml
<transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=3600000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?trace=true&amp;maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=3600000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

ActiveMQ log snippet:

```
2016-02-18 19:14:28,185 | INFO  | ActiveMQ.Advisory.Topic Inactive for longer than 30000 ms - removing ... | org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Topic | ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler
2016-02-18 19:16:18,839 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:53894 failed: org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityIOException: Channel was inactive for too (>10000) long: tcp://127.0.0.1:53894 | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker
```

Spring messaging TRACE logs:

```
TRACE 02/18 19:16:18,839 [reactor-tcp-io-6] - Received heart-beat in session o05rr4u5 
DEBUG 02/18 19:16:18,886 [reactor-tcp-io-6] - TCP connection to broker closed in session o05rr4u5 
DEBUG 02/18 19:16:18,886 [reactor-tcp-io-6] - Cleaning up connection state for session o05rr4u5 
TRACE 02/18 19:16:18,886 [clientOutboundChannel-44] - Encoding STOMP ERROR, headers={message=[Connection to broker closed.]} 
DEBUG 02/18 19:16:18,890 [clientInboundChannel-53] - Ignoring DISCONNECT in session o05rr4u5. Connection already cleaned up.
```

Appreciate if someone could please guide me on this.

Thanks,

Comment: <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?trace=true&amp;maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=3600000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>   this setting doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What are the actual heart-beat settings for the STOMP connection? With Stomp, heart-beating can be configured from the client side when connecting to the server. However I don't know how Spring configuration of this setting looks like.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322494/how-to-keep-stomp-connection-longer